# Is the nuclei and electrons distribution inside the Sun even or they form 'unbalanced distribution' layers?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, plasma-physics, sun

Is the nuclei and electrons distribution inside the Sun even or they form 'unbalanced distribution' layers? In simple words does the difference in mass or even density between nuclei and electrons cause the formation of layers with different plasma particles ratio?

Comment: How would that work, given that like charges repel and opposite charges attract?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the nuclei and electrons distribution inside the Sun even or they form 'unbalanced distribution' layers?

No, the deep interior of the [Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun) is a fully ionized [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)).  Plasmas are gases of ionized particles where the number of negative charges roughly equals that of positive, known as *quasi-neutrality*.  This results because electric fields do work to get rid of themselves, i.e., if too many of one charge type piles up, it will generate an electric field that will act to get rid of the pile up.

> In simple words does the difference in mass or even density between nuclei and electrons cause the formation of layers with different plasma particles ratio?

No, this would generate electric fields that would do work to get rid of themselves.